# Send email alert if duplicate workstation and/or duplicate port exists

Tags: powershell

I have a system that would be completely unusable by users if either a duplicate workstation or duplicate port exists in a .dat text file (Windows), and think a powershell script would help in reading the file at intervals to check for either of these conditions (without making changes). I would like to have an email sent which would contain info on what duplicates were found as well.

No header in the file; here's a sample of it:

```
WW1SI01LTJP,5459
OPAOGATB02,5460
WW1S101SPARE,5461
amichaud,5462
WT0080648a899c,5463
sbailie,5464
droberts,5465
WT0080648aaa2f,5466
WT008064865255,5467
nhxp557,5468
WT0080648aa8d2,5469
```

Comment: Is there a reason you included the spaces and hyphens here or can they be removed to match the actual file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for finding the duplicates:

```
$wsht = @{}
$portht = @{}


Get-Content 'c:\somedir\somefile.dat' | foreach {
 $parts = $_.split(',')
 $wsht[$parts[0]] += @($_)
 $portht[$parts[1]] += @($_)
 }

 $dupWs = $wsht.Values | 
  where {$_.count -gt 1 }

$dupPort = $portht.Values |
 where {$_.count -gt 1}

 $dupWs
 $dupPort
```

Comment: A variant of this would be to just increment the value of the hashtables (`$wsht[$parts[0]]++`) and extract duplicates like this: `$dupWs = $wsht.Keys | where { $wsht[$_] -gt 1 }`

Comment: Tested and this is what I was looking for; I can incorporate the email piece with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd import the file as a CSV and group by column:

```
$data = Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\your.dat' -Header 'Workstation','Port'

$dw = $data | group 'Workstation' | ? { $_.Count -gt 1 } | select -Expand Name
$dp = $data | group 'Port' | ? { $_.Count -gt 1 } | select -Expand Name

$data | ? { $dw -contains $_.Workstation -or $dp -contains $_.Port }

if ($dw -or $dp) {
  # send e-mail
}
```

Comment: This is a nice alternative but also looking for it to return the bad entries as the script from mjolinor does, so entries could be easily searched and corrected. I may be able to use this script elsewhere though. Thanks!